# Picketlink Source Compile Error

Tags: java, security, maven, jboss, picketlink

I am trying to compile picketlink from source but it keeps failing with the same error when running either mvn install or mvn package.

It always fails on 'PicketLink Identity Management API' with the error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project picketlink-idm-api: Compilation failure
error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have tried with versions 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.6.0, and 2.6.1.

Whats wrong and how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You can run mvn -X to get a stack trace for the NPE in the compilation process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compile using a web archive (war) package?  It also might help to start a new project with just the one dependency. It might help you narrow down the problem.